# What is the difference between Aspect and Flow Direction tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, aspect, flow-direction

There are two seemingly identical Spatial Analysis tools:

(1) Surface -> Aspect:

> Derives aspect from a raster surface. The aspect identifies the
>   downslope direction of the maximum rate of change in value from each
>   cell to its neighbors.
>
> Aspect can be thought of as the slope direction. The values of the
>   output raster will be the compass direction of the aspect.

(2) Hydrology -> Flow direction:

> Creates a raster of flow direction from each cell to its steepest
>   downslope neighbor.

## Manual comparison

To test this I created an aspect layer and a flow direction layer, converted the aspect layer to the [format of flow direction](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-flow-direction-works.htm) using Raster Calculator:

```
64*(("aspect" >= 0)  &  ("aspect" < 22.5)) + 
128*(("aspect" >= 22.5) & ("aspect" <67.5)) + 
1*(("aspect" >=67.5) & ("aspect" <112.5)) + 
2*(("aspect" >=112.5) & ("aspect" <157.5)) + 
4*(("aspect" >=157.5) & ("aspect" <202.5)) + 
8*(("aspect" >=202.5) & ("aspect" <247.5)) + 
16*(("aspect" >=247.5) & ("aspect" <292.5)) + 
32*(("aspect" >=292.5) & ("aspect" <337.5)) + 
64*(("aspect" >=337.5) & ("aspect" <=360))
```

and then compared to the flow direction layer:

```
("aspect_conv" == "flowdir")
```

**The vast majority of the resulting layer is 1 (true)** and I suppose the few areas with 0 is because of flat aspects or nulls.

It therefore appears that the only difference is that "Flow Direction" returns unique values (powers of 2), while aspect returns a continuous range of floats. Is that all?

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in your tests and data results, i would say the same as you :

> "the only difference is that "Flow Direction" **returns unique values**
>   (powers of 2) while aspect returns a **continuous range of floats**"

I would add Flow Direction is a sort of subtool (maybe somewhere based on the aspect tool and doing exactly what you did) used to precisely create the requisite coded output of 8 neighbourood cells flow direction needed in the D8 flow direction model (Réf. Jenson and Domingue, 1988 below) on which all esri tools are based for their hydrological analysis :

> **FLOW DIRECTIONS**
>
> The second procedure of the conditioning phase builds the flow direction data 
>   set (Table 3). The flow direction for a cell is the direction water will flow 
>   out of the cell. It is encoded to correspond to the orientation of one of the 
>   eight cells that surround the cell (x) as follows:
>
> 64 128 1
>   32 x 2
>   16 8 4
>
> For example, if cell x flows to the left in the matrix, its flow direction will be encoded as a 32. Flow direction encoding is done in powers of two so that surround conditions correspond to unique values when the powers of two are summed for any unique set of neighbors.

**Source**

> S. K. Jenson and J. O. Domingue, “Extracting Topographic Structure
>   from Digital Elevation Data for Geographic Information System
>   Analysis,” Photogrammetric Engineering and Remote Sensing, Vol. 54,
>   1988, pp. 1593-1600

Download here : http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.138.6487&rep=rep1&type=pdf